# popup not closing on clicking again

Tags: jquery

I have to use a popup script where popup was toggled using true or false value of a variable. like so:

```
var iconvideoneww = true;

$('.icontrigger').click(function(){
if(iconvideoneww){
$('.iconvideopop').fadeIn(80);
}
    else{
$('.iconvideopop').fadeOut(80);    
    }
    iconvideoneww =!iconvideoneww;
});
```

And toggling works fine. Problem is, that I also need a script where clicking anywhere outside it hides the popup. Now then i add such a script, what happens is that the popup is still in the 'if' step of the above code and clicking anywhere outside it at this point hides it, now if i click again at the trigger button to open the popup, the code starts going to the 'else' step, whereas i want it to go to the 'if'. the code for hiding popup on clicking anywhere outside is:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (event) {
    var container1 = $(".tagevent-content");
    if (container1.has(event.target).length === 0) {
        container1.hide();
        toggleEventState = false;
    }
});
```

fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/p969ohh7/
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you do:

Register click on the image for showing the pop-up. Register another click on the document for hiding it *but* prevent the clicking events to bubble up from the pop-up with [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

https://jsfiddle.net/p969ohh7/5/

```
$(".icontrigger").click(function (e) {
    var $popup = $(".iconvideopop");
    if (!$popup.is(":visible")) {
        $popup.fadeIn(80);
    } else {
        $popup.fadeOut(80);
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function () {
    var $popup = $(".iconvideopop");
    if ($popup.is(":visible")) {
        $popup.fadeOut(80);
    }
});

$(".iconvideopop").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would leave the popup status variable alone and act on the status of the actual element:

```
$('.icontrigger').click(function(){
    var $popup =  $('.iconvideopop');
    if (!$popup.is(':visible')) {
        $popup.fadeIn(80);
    } else {
        $popup.fadeOut(80);    
    }
});
```

I am using $popup to store the jQuery element, simply to avoid asking for it 3 times using the selector... Using is(':visible') will be more accurate as it checks directly the status of the element, and determines the action to be taken accordingly.

You could also use an object to do the work, or you could change the onmouseup event when displaying the popup. Removing it when the popup is not displayed, this will be the optimal step, but for just one event it's not really needed IMO.

EDIT: Here's the object I had in mind...

```
var toggleable = function(selector){
    return {
        $element:$(selector),
        toggle:function(){ //Decides to display or hide the element.
            if (!this.$element.is(':visible')) {
                this.show();
            } else {
                this.hide();    
            }
        },
        show:function(){ //Displays the element
             this.$element.fadeIn(80);
        },
        hide:function(){ //Hides the element
             this.$element.fadeOut(80);
        }
    };
}

var iconvideopop = toggleable('.iconvideopop');
$('.icontrigger').click(function(){iconvideopop.toggle();});
$(document).mouseup(function(){iconvideopop.hide();});
```

EDIT2: To prevent the pop-up to close when it is clicked (as we listen on the document for a click), it is recommended to do the following:

```
function myEventHandler(event){
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.iconvideopop').length) {
        //We clicked anywhere on the document BUT on .iconvideopop or its children. We can therefor close the pop-up.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but there is one problem: clicking anywhere inside the popup is also hiding it, which it should not

Comment: Or you can use .toggle() ;)

Comment: Nope, jQuery.toggle() uses slideDown and slideUp as transition... So it wouldn't be exactly like OP wanted. :)

Comment: @user3450590 this is because you are binding the hide function on the document event... Let's see what you could do...